Fully block the onClick event coming from a decoy Marker (android-maps-compose)
I am trying to add a Marker with a glow to the google map. For this, I use a simple Marker and another Marker with a bitmap mask and animated alpha. The second marker is a decoy whose sole purpose is to show a glow behind the main marker. I want only the main marker to be the sole consumer of onClick.
Ideally, the glow marker stays behind the main marker and never interacts with the user input. I don't need the default onClick behavior coming from it, I don't want ANY onClick event firing off from that marker, and I want it to stay behind the non-glow marker at all times with the main marker handling all the user input from onClick?.invoke().
The problem is that the glow marker consumes the onClick event due to the layered nature of my marker composition. When the non-glow marker is clicked, I expect a modal bottom sheet to appear and it does appear. Easy. However, when I click, seamingly, on the non-glow marker, the glowing marker seems to capture the click, thus, not triggering my bottom sheet (even though it should). As far as zIndex is concerned, it doesn't appear to affect the behavior as much as I want it to, i.e. the problem persists.
Link to the video. Notice the extra click between the expanded and hidden states of the bottom sheet.
The code:
@Composable
fun LocationPin(
    glowBitmap: BitmapDescriptor?,
    noGlowBitmap: BitmapDescriptor?,
    position: LatLng,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onClick: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = position)
    val glowMarkerState = rememberMarkerState(position = position)
    val glowAlpha = remember { Animatable(0f) }

    LaunchedEffect(isSelected) {
        if (isSelected) {
            glowAlpha.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f, animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 2500)
            )
        } else glowAlpha.snapTo(0f)
    }
 

    Marker(
        state = markerState,
        icon = noGlowBitmap,
        alpha = 1f,
        zIndex = -1f,
        onClick = {
            onClick?.invoke()
            Log.d("LocationPin", "clicked no glow")
            true
        })

    if (isSelected) {
        Marker(
            state = glowMarkerState,
            icon = glowBitmap,
            alpha = glowAlpha.value,
            zIndex = 1f,
            onClick = {
                Log.d("LocationPin", "clicked with glow")
                true
            }
        )
    }
}

If what I am trying to achieve with the decoy marker is not possible, is there any reliable way to apply the glow as a decoy behind the Marker? Ideally the decoy should change its scale in response to camera zoom similarly to how the Marker does it.
Logs:
19:28:52.146  D  clicked no glow
19:28:59.580  D  clicked with glow
19:29:00.768  D  clicked no glow
19:29:02.165  D  clicked with glow
19:29:02.897  D  clicked no glow
19:29:04.119  D  clicked with glow
19:29:04.757  D  clicked no glow
19:29:34.243  D  clicked with glow
19:29:35.291  D  clicked no glow
19:29:37.246  D  clicked with glow
19:29:38.188  D  clicked no glow
19:29:39.982  D  clicked with glow
19:29:41.586  D  clicked no glow


Upd: The problem can be solved if I assign the onClick?.invoke() call to each onClick parameter of both markers, but it rather seems like a "hack". It would be nice to know whether the onclick event listener of an android-compose-marker can be blocked enitrely.

It sounds like the second marker is meant to be visual effect only.  Would it work better to define two different marker icons and switch between the two as needed?
Starting with the createBitmapDescriptor function, you should be able to create a bitmap with a glow effect.
And then use a different icon depending on whether the marker is the selected icon.  For example, this code uses a different icon depending on features of the marker

At some point I had code similar to the you suggested: show a specific marker based on a condition. The issue I encountered was that the substitution of the markers was not always seamless. Occasionally, I would see the marker flicker for a brief period of time which I assume was caused by recomposition. I even sometimes tried to create all the required bitmaps at the parent component and pass them down as parameters, but the flicker would persist.
The dirty solution for now is to keep both the mask (glow) marker in sync with the main one (same parameters, callbacks and their usage).

Thanks for letting us know.  This is something we should look into when we have time.
